# Can't you hack the upvote system in overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, down-votes, sock-puppets

I just noticed something from the Mathematical Community. I had a question with 2 downvotes, (and I had 1 reputation before), making me still have 1 reputation. Then, for some reason, this random person upvoted it, making me have 6 reputation. Even though the question still has one downvote, I still got 5 more reputation. Doesn't that mean that if you have like 10 accounts on, for example, SO(even though you aren't supposed to) and you posted a really really dumb question on it, and even though your question got 5 downvotes, you could still improve your reputation a lot by upvoting using your other accounts?

Comment: Well if you delete it, then all the reputation from both upvotes and downvotes will be reversed anyways. Past that, creating sock-puppets will quickly be detected, and will only result in a suspension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not that easy (actually impossible) mister (or mam).

This is called serial voting and you will be caught by the system. This is to prevent others from giving others free rep and prevent fraud. This is not tolerated and will probably give you and other offenders a nice suspension and next account deletion. Moderators will know who was involved so they can take the right actions and the right users. Vote fraud could also be what you are attempting to do like what Nathan Tuggy said. Either way, you get in big, big trouble.

So don't try. You will fail and get suspended and eventually account deletion if you dare continue. For more information read this link: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

If you delete the question, you lose all rep earned/gain all rep lost through that question. So deleting only brings you back to the amount of rep you had before posting the question so your rep change is: 0.

Comment: I never said I did it on purpose O:

Comment: @user3576467 How would you serial upvote accidentally? ;)

Comment: This isn't serial voting; it *is* vote fraud, though, by sockpuppeting. And that's an offense that can be dealt with by suspending or deleting the main account, and will almost always include deleting the socks.

Comment: @DavidPostill Maybe there was a script that was supposed to serially *downvote*, but it accidentally sent the request for upvote instead of downvote. :P